# Removing multiple line patterns not working when patterns are stored in a file

Tags: regex, shell, sed, pattern-matching

I had asked a question about searching for multiple lines which I found answers to here: [Searching for multiple lines including a blank one in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735865/searching-for-multiple-lines-including-a-blank-one-in-shell-script/9736045#comment12382055_9736045)

However, if I store multiple such command in a  file and execute them, then the first search goes through fine, however on searching for subsequent patterns, I get a blank output from sed.

That is if I store,

```
sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${ g; s/<Pattern1>\n<pattern2> //g p }' file-name
sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${ g; s/<Pattern3>\n<pattern4> //g p }' file-name
```

in a file and then execute each line in the this file using the `eval` keyword, then the first sed replaces the first multi-line patterns, i.e. `pattern1`, followed by `pattern2`, however, it returns a blank output even though the file contains these patterns. Any clues?

Comment: Re: "I [...] execute each line in the this file using the `eval` keyword": Are you sure that's a good idea? `eval` is a very powerful, dangerous hammer, and it doesn't seem appropriate here.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute each line in the this file using the `eval` keyword"?

Comment: I have stored the entire sed commands for the specific patterns in a file. I will read this file line by line and execute each command on the shell script.

Comment: you'll have to convince us that there is no other solution except to use `eval` (not a good idea!). So that means showing us more of what you're trying to do with a nicely formated question using the format controls at the top of the edit box (note {} is for presenting source code). Consider including sample input, required output, current output and code that isn't working. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you want to do, but I'm guessing that you want to remove a pair of lines if the first line matches `Pattern1` and the second matches `Pattern2` or if the first line matches `Pattern3` and the second matches `Pattern4`.  If so, the following should work for you:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<\EOF |
Mary

John
Doe
Simon
Henry
EOF
sed -n -e 'H; ${ g
  # append a newline to correctly match at the end of the file
  s/$/\n/
  # delete instances of John\nDoe
  s/\nJohn\nDoe\n/\n/g
  # delete instances of Mary\n<blank>
  s/\nMary\n\n/\n/g
  # remove the newlines added at the beginning and end
  s/\n\(.*\)\n/\1/
  # print the result
  p
}'
# output:
# Simon
# Henry
```

The above sed script uses `H` instead of `1h; 1!H` to get a newline at the beginning of the pattern.  It also adds a newline at the end.  This makes it possible to search for `\nPattern1\nPattern2\n` instead of `Pattern1\nPattern2`.  This prevents bad matches:  searching for "Anne Doe" shouldn't find "MaryAnne Doe" and searching for "John Clark" shouldn't find "John Clarkson".